# Wenn schon, denn schon / Wennschon, dennschon

Tags: etymology, spelling

Ich war sehr verwundert, als ich gestern gelernt habe, dass „wenn schon, denn schon“ falsch ist und es richtig zusammengeschrieben wird: „wennschon, dennschon“ ([Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wennschon)).

Meine Herleitung war

> 1. Wenn ich jetzt schon da bin, dann feier ich schon auch mit!
> 2. Wenn schon, dann schon!
> 3. Wenn schon, denn schon!

Ist diese Herleitung richtig? Falls nein, woher kommt „wennschon, dennschon“? Und warum werden „wennschon“ und „dennschon“ zusammengeschrieben?

Comment: Gibt es da eine Verbindung? Ich habe gelernt, dass "wennschon" und "dennschon" Konjunktionen sind, die an sich nichts mit "wenn" und "schon" zu tun haben. Kann mich aber auch irren.

Comment: Wiktionary listet [wenn schon, denn schon](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/wenn_schon,_denn_schon) als alternative Schreibweise zu "wennschon, dennschon". Ich befürchte aber, dass das eher daher rührt, dass es die meisten Menschen so schreiben, es aber strikt genommen immer noch falsch ist.

Comment: @Kaj Torvald Grey, ich habe keine Ahung, daher Frage ist. Die Bedeutung in wiktionary ist aber auch "**wenn schon** etwas (unter Umständen Bedenkliches) überhaupt getan wird, dann soll es aber auch ausgiebig und gründlich, ordentlich, richtig oder dergleichen getan werden".

Comment: Und wo ist der bedeutungsmäßige Unterschied zwischen dem vom Duden erläuternden *umgangssprachlich: wenn man es schon tun will, dann aber auch gründlich*

Comment: @Thomas Dittmar, ich sehe keinen Unterschied. Mir ging es um den Widerspruch 'wennschon' im Titel, aber 'wenn schon' im Text zur Bedeutung.

Comment: Ich würde "wenn schon" nie im Leben zusammenschreiben, da kann der Duden vermelden, was er will. Ich glaube auch nicht, dass es für die meisten Hörer eine intransparente Bildung ohne Bezug zu "wenn" und "schon" ist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zur Herkunft von *wennschon* habe ich sehr wenig bis nichts in den gängigen Quellen (DWDS, Wörterbuchnetz, canoo.net) gefunden. Jedoch findet man einiges zu verwandten Konjunktionen.

*Wennschon* ist eine konzessive Konjunktion (einräumend, entgegengesetzt), die synonym zu unter anderem *wenngleich*, *obgleich*, *obschon*, *obwohl* und *wenn auch* ist.
Mit Ausnahme von *wenn auch* werden heutzutage alle diese Konjunktionen als ein Wort geschrieben. Wie ich aus dem DWDS entnehmen konnte, wurden *obschon*, *obgleich*, *obzwar* und *obwohl* durchaus im 16. und 17. Jahrhundert getrennt geschrieben.

> obwohl (17. Jh.), älter obwoln, ob wol (16. Jh.), ob(e) … wol(e) (15. Jh.); obgleich (16. Jh.), bis ins 18. Jh. daneben ob gleich, ob … gleich (16. Jh.); obschon (16. Jh.), bis ins 18. Jh. auch ob schon (16. Jh.), ob … schon (15. Jh.), mhd. (vereinzelt) obe schōne; obzwar (Ende 18. Jh.), zuvor ob zwar (17. Jh.), ob … zwar (16. Jh.)

Hieraus schließend denke ich, dass es für Wortverbindungen mit *wenn* gleiches gilt. Der Redensarten-Index stützt diese These, denn dort wird angedeutet, dass die Verbindungen von *ob* **und** *wenn* mit *schon* gleicherweise entstanden sind.

> Bereits im 16. Jahrhundert festigt sich die Bindung zwischen "ob" bzw. "wenn" und "schon", die ein konzessives Verhältnis ausdrückt und sich somit auf eine Bedingung bezieht, deren erwartete Wirkung sich nicht erfüllt.

Was die Zusammenschreibweise angeht, stimmt das vermutlich auch für *wiewohl*, nachweislich hingegen auf jeden Fall für *trotzdem*.

> trotzdem Konj. ‘dennoch’ (19. Jh.), aus trotz dem, daß …

Die getrennte Form *wenn ... schon* ist semantisch zu differenzieren, weil das *schon* in der Regel eine modale Bedeutungen hat, jedoch nicht teil der Konjunktion ist. Da *wennschon* aber ein recht hohen Seltenheitswert hat, *wenn ... schon* dagegen häufig vorkommt, liegt es nahe *wennschon* versehentlich als *wenn schon* zu schreiben.

Nichtsdestotrotz wird's aber auch in den Wendungen zusammengeschrieben. Während es in manchen Wendungen durchaus möglich erscheint, dass es auf das modale *schon* zurückgeführt werden könnte, ist dies nicht der Fall. Im Falle von *wennschon, dennschon* hat *wennschon* ebenfalls die konzessive Bedeutung. Es wird Bezug auf etwas genommen, was eigentlich eine Belastung ist und man nicht gerne machen möchte. *Wennschon* suggeriert also den Widerspruch dazu. Es impliziert also: "Wennschon es anstrengend ist, mache ich das. Dann aber wenigstens richtig." => Wennschon, dennschon.

Wenn nun *wennschon* zusammengeschrieben wird, so ist *dennschon* konsequenterweise natürlich auch zusammenzuschreiben.

Abschließend kann ich noch mal den Redensarten-Index zitieren und nehme hier Bezug auf "Na, und wennschon".

> "Wennschon" hat sich zu der Bedeutung "na und?", "was macht das schon?", "das ist egal!" u.ä. entwickelt, die sich ebenfalls auf die Erwartungen von Sprecher und Hörer bezieht.

Kombiniert mit dem Auszug, den ich oben angeführt habe, heißt das also, dass das *wennschon* impliziert, dass etwas entgegen meiner Erwartung nicht eingetreten ist. Im Laufe der Jahre entwickelte sich hier die Bedeutung der Gleichgültigkeit. Sozusagen "Wennschon es nicht eingetreten ist, macht mir das nichts." => Und wennschon.

Comment: Kann nicht anders - Bei deinen Aufzählungen fiel mir sofort der Kohlen-Juke aus dem König Kalle Wirsch ein...

Comment: Nichtsdestotrotz :) http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5313/benutzung-von-nichtsdestotrotz-nichtsdestotrotz-usage